# Robolectric tests fail on ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs

Tags: android, robolectric

in my app I'm calling ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs and my Robolectric test fails with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDirs(Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/io/File;
    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatKitKat.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextCompatKitKat.java:29)
    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextCompat.java:216)
    at com.mondiamedia.mmplaylistapp.helpers.SongFileHelper.getMyPlaylistSongsFolder(SongFileHelper.java:73)
    at com.mondiamedia.mmplaylistapp.helpers.SongFileHelper.getNewMyPlaylistSongFile(SongFileHelper.java:48)
    at com.mondiamedia.mmplaylistapp.helpers.SongFileHelperTest.testGetNewMyPlaylistSongFileWithValidSong(SongFileHelperTest.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I looked at the ContextCompat.java and the culprit seems to be this part:

```
final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (version >= 19) {
            return ContextCompatKitKat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, type);
        } else {
            final File single;
            if (version >= 8) {
                single = ContextCompatFroyo.getExternalFilesDir(context, type);
```

In the test I put @Config(emulateSdk = 18) but it seems that Robolectric still runs it as SDK 19 so the ContextCompatKitKat class gets called. Does anyone have any idea how to prevent this error? The obvious solution would be to call ContextCompatFroyo but I don't know if there are any unwanted side effects.